# Getting data from inner class of data class

Tags: android

Adapter

```
holder.tv_item_title.setText(dataList.get(position).getTitle());
```

AllResponse

```
public class AllResponse {

    public AllResponse(List<WishResponseList> wishResponseListList) {
        this.wishResponseListList = wishResponseListList;
    }

    List<WishResponseList> wishResponseListList;

    private class WishResponseList {

        int id;
        String title;
        String contents;
        String writer;
        boolean clear;
        String color;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
    }
}
```

CallBack

```
public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response)
```

I am trying to set data from MainActivity to data class, and use it in Adapter class. Before this way, I'd tried it by kotlin class but `:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac` compilation error occurred. How can I get inner class' data?